# Phoenix Ecto Unique Validation: constraint error when attempting to insert struct

Tags: validation, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Ran this migration in order to have unique index on account number

```
  def change do
    create unique_index(:users, [:account_number])
  end
```

And then in the model:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :city, :postal_code, :country, :login_count, :last_login, :active, :account_number, :password])
    |> validate_required([:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :city, :postal_code, :country, :account_number])
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 8, max: 100)
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> unique_constraint(:account_number)
    |> put_pass_hash()
  end
```

Produces this error:

```
 ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

     * unique: users_account_number_index

 If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
 call unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
 constraint name. The changeset has not defined any constraint.
```

PostgreSQL 9.6
Phoenix 1.2.4
Ecto 2.1.4

What am I missing?

Comment: `The changeset has not defined any constraint.` is strange. Are you sure that this `changeset` function is in the `User` model and you're inserting a Changeset returned by this function?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is using 
`Ecto.Changeset.unique_constraint/2`
The error says you should use `Ecto.Changeset.unique_constraint/3` which means you must add options. In this case just add constraint error message with the `message` option key

Change

`|>unique_constraint(:account_number)`

to

`|>unique_constraint(:account_number, message: "Account number must be unique or some message like that")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could happen because you try to insert existing :account number.
There are 2 ways to fix it:

1. If you need to keep those field unique, just be sure that you insert the unique one
2. Otherwise you can remove `unique_constraint` from your schema and make non-unique index in your DB like so:

```
  def change do
    drop unique_index(:users, [:account_number])
    create index(:users, [:account_number])
  end
```